# Corrupted Excel File & 7zip

Tags: excel, 7zip, corruption

I have a problem with a corrupted excel file. So far I have used 7zip to open it as an archive and extract most of the data. But some important sheets cannot be extracted.

Using the l command of 7zip I get the following output :

```
7z.exe l -slt "C:\Users\corrupted1.xlsm" xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml
```

**Output:**

```
Listing archive: C:\Users\corrupted1.xlsm

--
Path = C:\Users\corrupted1.xlsm
Type = zip
Physical Size = 11931916

----------
Path = xl\worksheets\sheet3.xml
Folder = -
Size = 57217
Packed Size = 12375
Modified = 1980-01-01 00:00:00
Created =
Accessed =
Attributes = .....
Encrypted = -
Comment =
CRC = 553C3C52
Method = Deflate
Host OS = FAT
Version = 20
```

However when trying to extract it (or test it for that matter) I get :

```
7z.exe t -slt "C:\Users\corrupted1.xlsm" xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml
```

**Output:**

```
Processing archive: C:\Users\corrupted1.xlsm

Testing     xl\worksheets\sheet3.xml     Unsupported Method

Sub items Errors: 1
```

The method listed above says **Deflate**, which is the same for all the worksheets.

Is there anything I can do? What kind of corruption is this? Is it the CRC? Can I ignore it somehow or something?

Please help!

**Edit:**
The following is the error when trying to extract or edit the xml file through 7zip:
[image: 7zip error]

**Edit 2:**
Tried with WinZip as well, getting :

```
Extracting to "C:\Users\axpavl\AppData\Local\Temp\wzf0b9\"
Use Path: yes   Overlay Files: yes
Extracting xl\worksheets\sheet2.xml
Unable to find the local header for xl\worksheets\sheet2.xml.
Severe Error: Cannot find a local header.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:
https://superuser.com/questions/145479/excel-edit-the-xml-inside-an-xlsx-file

and this on too: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/recover-data-from-a-damaged-office-file-with-the-help-of-7-zip/

Comment: I have already encountered these solutions, and they worked ok for me for most of the worksheets. However the ones with the problem cannot be extracted at all, nor editted.